# How to just select first line of a HTML file using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have about 600 HTML files and I want to select the first line of that files that is something like a **title** and I just need that first line, not others.

I am going to create a program to select each file and just select the first line

```
for($i=1;$i<=607;$i++){
    if($i>=1 and $i<10){
        $prefix='0';
    }else{
        $prefix='';
    }
    $text=file_get_contents($prefix.$i.'.htm');
    //if I select the first line, that whould be <html>
}
```

But that is HTML and almost each file has it own style, I mean one is in `<b>` and anther is in `<h4>` and so on...

**What is your suggestion?**

Comment: Try dom http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 0):

Well,

- [load file to DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php)
- use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php) to get **title** element content

Comment: Please read my question again, I said each file has different style and that is title. If it was just title I could do it by my own programming

Comment: You dont have to extract *title* element exactly. Just grab with xpath whatever you want. E.g. text content of whole HTML file.